# Mutual information inequality for features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, information-theory, mutual-information

Suppose I have a dataset $X$ being regressed to corresponding $Y$. Suppose that $X \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and we derive features $\phi_1, \phi_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ that are simply coordinates 1 and 2 of $X$. I would like to quantify the information content and dependence in and between $\phi_1, \phi_2$. Thus, my question is: is there some inequality that relates $I(\phi_1, Y), I(\phi_2, Y), I(X, Y)$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are functions of $X$, the [data processing inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality) says that:

$$I(\phi_1, Y) \le I(X,Y)$$
$$I(\phi_2, Y) \le I(X,Y)$$

Note that this is true for any functions of $X$, not only functions that return the individual coordinates. As a consequence of the above inequalities, we also have that:

$$I(\phi_1, Y) + I(\phi_2, Y) \le 2 I(X,Y)$$

A general inequality comparing $I(\phi_1, Y)$ to $I(\phi_2, Y)$ alone can't exist since, whatever inequality holds for a particular problem, the opposite will be true for a problem where we flip the coordinates of $X$.

Comment: Independent of ordering, I'm curious if there exists something such as a triangle inequality, ie. $I(\phi_1, Y) + I(\phi_2, Y) \leq I(X, Y)$?

Comment: Will accept this answer if there are no tighter bounds that anyone knows of that are less than $2I(X;Y)$.

Comment: @goodcow I edited the answer to include something similar to what you asked. $I(\phi_1,Y) + I(\phi_2,Y)$ must be less than or equal to $2 I(X,Y)$, not $I(X,Y)$. For example, consider the case where the features are identical, so $I(\phi_1,Y) = I(\phi_2,Y) = I(X,Y)$. If you're interested in triangle inequality type relations, you might also take a look at the 'variation of information', which is a true distance metric based on the mutual information (so it satisfies the triangle inequality).